# In GLSL (330 or otherwise) what could cause a uniform struct to behave differently than a variable struct?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am experiencing a strange issue in OpenGL 3.3. I defined a struct called `Dual` with `vec4` members "u" and "v", and began writing and testing functions, like the "sandwich product" you'll see later in my snippet (I included the implementation, but it should be irrelevant.) During this testing, I used two individual `vec4` uniforms, calling them "u" and "v" to make their future purpose clear, and simply made Duals on the fly from those. When I was satisfied with the behavior, I made a uniform Dual called "model" (as in model-view-projection) and set about swapping references to the standalone vectors for references to model's members. I got a black screen, but no errors.

I've reworked my vertex shader until the issue can be enabled/disabled just by toggling comments on two lines:

```
#version 330

struct Dual { vec4 u, v; };

// (...)

// This should be agnostic to where the args come from
// It was and is correct given local variables/values
Dual sandwich(Dual u, Dual v) { return mul(mul(u, v), conj(u)); }

uniform mat4 projection;

const vec4 u0 = vec4(1,0,0,0), v0 = vec4(0,0,0,0);
uniform vec4 u = u0, v = v0;
uniform Dual model = Dual(u0, v0);

in vec4 pos_in;
out vec4 pos_out;

void main(){
        // Swizzling 'xyz' and then 'yzw' adapts GLSL 'xyzw' to/from 'wxyz'
        // It may look strange, but again, it works for local values
        Dual x = Dual(u0, vec4(0, pos_in.xyz)),
                // mxm = sandwich(model, x); // -> big black canvas
                mxm = sandwich(Dual(u, v), x); // -> big rainbow square
        gl_Position = projection * vec4(mxm.v.yzw, 1);
        pos_out = gl_Position;
}
```

In my C++ code, I've tried setting the values once after initialization, once per key press to different presets, even once per frame, but for now I'm relying on the default initialization in the shader until I press a key - here's what that looks like:

```
auto mu = program.locate("model.u"), mv = program.locate("model.v"),
        u = program.locate("u"), v = program.locate("v");
// ...key 1 is pressed, so set both pairs to the Dual identity...
glUniform4f(mu, 1, 0, 0, 0); glUniform4f(mv, 0, 0, 0, 0);
glUniform4f(u, 1, 0, 0, 0);  glUniform4f(v, 0, 0, 0, 0);
// ...key 2 is pressed, set both to something else, and so on
```

Of course my first guess was that I was locating the members wrong, but that's the syntax I've seen elsewhere, and I don't see a typo, either. Since there's no associated error with an unknown name, I checked the locations for the telltale -1, but `model.u` and `model.v` report 0 and 1, respectively.

Using the constants "u0" and "v0" to initialize both the `vec4`s and model's members, but as a sanity check of sorts, I tried initializing them by value. The behavior was exactly the same, as it should be - why *would* using a value produce a different result than a variable initialized to that value? Even if I play the devil's advocate and assume there is some difference, why wouldn't the same issue affect the standalone "u" and "v" when they're initialized to the named variables "u0" and "v0" as opposed to the values they were given?

Comment: Does `uniform Dual model = Dual(vec4(1,0,0,0), vec4(0,0,0,0));` works?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I know. But `u,v` are not used in `model` initialization, which seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Rabbid76: It is never an error to set a uniform whose location is -1.

Comment: Using values instead of the const variables didn't change either version. In fact, ignoring the default value and setting the members from my C++ code didn't change anything either. The same goes for defining model in terms of u and v as opposed to defining all of the above in terms of u0 and v0.

Comment: I understand that the offending line is `mxm = sandwich(model, x);`. If you can show a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) things may become clear.

Comment: @Ripi2 Thank you. I'll work on that. In the mean time, would seeing the repo help? https://github.com/jep-dev/geometric -> `make -j bin/view`. Note that whichever you use, model or u/v, the unused one will (likely?) be eliminated and hence the location will be reported as -1. (I tried adding an expression to force u/v into use/locations when using model, but it's clever enough to see that the value it produced was discarded, so currently model has locations 0/1 and u/v report location -1.)

Comment: I completed the MCVE... and was not able to reproduce the problem. My code doesn't call glUniform, except to set the projection matrix, which at least tells me the default value is okay (both the const variables and literals) and that model and locals/temporaries are equivalent. I'll keep digging, but I can still post the MCVE if you'd like (it's still about 300 lines / 250 wloc, but not 2500.)

Comment: I'm not sure if I should consider this question solved or not - the problem wasn't reproducible, so there is no "different behavior". All the same, it may take me a while to track down the issue, because the MCVE was mostly code copied from the original. The last thing I tried was binding a key to print model's value, and using that, I can see that model is both initialized and later set/reset correctly. That should make my C++ code irrelevant, and yet the shader in the MCVE is a literal copy... where does that leave me? I might as well migrate to where the shader is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
const vec4 u0 = vec4(1,0,0,0), v0 = vec4(0,0,0,0);
uniform vec4 u = u0, v = v0;
uniform Dual model = Dual(u0, v0);
```

These three lines initialize `u0, v0, u, v, model`. These initializations with provided values are done **at link time**.

I cannot find in the GLSL specs a word about the order of global variables. The closest I found is at *4.2 Scoping*:

> Within a declaration, the scope of a name starts immediately after the
>   initializer if present or immediately after the name being declared if
>   not.

But "scope" is not he same as "order or initialization".

So it could be that `model` is being initialized before `u0, v0` and so those values are undefined.

The safe way (which does not depend on different vendors implementation) is not relying in other global vars, and instead use:

```
uniform Dual model = Dual(vec4(1,0,0,0), vec4(0,0,0,0));
```

Comment: Oh, I did that: "as a sanity check of sorts, I tried initializing them by value. The behavior was exactly the same" -- the working version continued to work and the broken one stayed broken.

Comment: Since the values in `model` are overridden after linking by the values supplied by `glUniform4f`, I don't think this will make a difference in this case. But in general, the answer is correct.

Comment: @BDL No. Sorry, the only glUniform4f calls are called when I press specific keys. If it worked until I pressed a key, I would have more to go on. Like I said, I tried using glUniform in all different places thinking that the default value was to blame, so if those are in fact overriding the default, pressing a key (setting model to the identity dual) would fix the problem. Instead, before *and* after using glUniform, the screen is black. With or without glUniform calls, it is as if model were zeroed, whereas the standalone u and v are fine by default and fine with glUniform.

Comment: @Rabbid76 [wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)): "Platform Issue (Unknown): Some drivers do not implement uniform initializers correctly"

Comment: @Ripi2 - yeah, I got that impression too, hence the use of const u0/v0 as opposed to defining model in terms of uniforms like u/v. It's fair to assume there are problems with const variables too, but the fact that it has one permanent definition in the same expression as its declaration means that anything that references its name is in the same context where it's given value, or else there would be a compilation error. I would kill for a compilation error.